# How paginate result of http response with laravel livewire

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I want to populate a table with calling HTTP request and fetch a JSON fine,
I set up live wire like this which can properly populate the table:

```
  public function render()
{
    $this->response = Http::timeout(30)->get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/lines')->body();


    return view('livewire.line-index', ['lines' =>json_decode($this->response)])->layout('layouts.app', ['header' => 'Line Management']);
}
```

but when I add paginate like this:

```
  public function render()
{
    $this->response = Http::timeout(30)->get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/lines')->body();


    return view('livewire.line-index', ['lines' =>json_decode($this->response)->paginate(25)])->layout('layouts.app', ['header' => 'Line Management']);
}
```

I see this error:

```
Call to a member function paginate() on array
```

Comment: `paginate()` must be called on a query builder instance, not "anything". You could make a macro for a paginator on a collection, then just convert the response to a collection before paginating it.

Comment: @Qirel I convert it to the collection, but still can not paginate the collection `$collection = collect(json_decode($this->response));

        return view('livewire.line-index', ['lines' =>$collection->paginate(25)])->layout('layouts.app', ['header' => 'Line Management']);`  but still see this `Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::paginate does not exist.`

Comment: ...but to do that you have to create a macro that paginates a collection, like I said.

Comment: @Qirel Thanks. it works as a reference  here the way how to create macro `https://gist.github.com/simonhamp/549e8821946e2c40a617c85d2cf5af5e`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
need to convert array to the collection and then creating a macro for using pagination on

```
collection.
 public function render()
    {
        $this->response = Http::timeout(30)->get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/lines')->body();

        $collection = collect(json_decode($this->response));
     
        return view('livewire.line-index', ['lines' =>$collection->paginate(20)])->layout('layouts.app', ['header' => 'Line Management']);
    }
```

For creating a macro you need to update the AppServiceProvider.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        /**
         * Paginate a standard Laravel Collection.
         *
         * @param int $perPage
         * @param int $total
         * @param int $page
         * @param string $pageName
         * @return array
         */
        Collection::macro('paginate', function($perPage, $total = null, $page = null, $pageName = 'page') {
            $page = $page ?: LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage($pageName);

            return new LengthAwarePaginator(
                $this->forPage($page, $perPage),
                $total ?: $this->count(),
                $perPage,
                $page,
                [
                    'path' => LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
                    'pageName' => $pageName,
                ]
            );
        });
    }
}
```

Reference: https://gist.github.com/simonhamp/549e8821946e2c40a617c85d2cf5af5e